# CSS convention for rgb colors

Tags: html, css, colors, sass, rgb

Is there any convention for `css` rgb color values? I mean- sholud the values be separated with spaces or should they not?

For example- should it look like this:

```
.some_element_class {
    color: rgb(100,100,100);
}
```

Or like this?:

```
.some_element_class {
    color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: convention really depends on the people you work with. Otherwise, there's really no meaning to convention if you're doing a solo project. Just make sure you understand what you've written.

Comment: Pick one and keep it consistent through out the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [W3 org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color), it can be used with and without spaces.

My advice is for you to use the one you like better and follow that in all your projects. If you get to work for a company follow their code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first one is superior because it uses less symbols and the readability is the same. But the most important thing is to be consistent.